# 403 Error while trying to request external API using Client credentials grant type

Tags: oauth-2.0, mule4

I am trying to request GET/POST operations on external API from my flow. I am using OAuth2 Client credentials grant type for authentication as mentioned [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/http-connector/1.7/http-authentication#oauth2-client-authentication). However, it keeps giving 403 Forbidden error:  "Message": "User is not authorized to access this resource with an explicit deny"
I removed refresh token from the configuration XML as mentioned [here](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/question/0D52T000050g5wPSAQ/i-am-trying-to-use-clientcredential-or-password-as-granttype-to-connect-from-mule-4-to-azure-but-either-i-got-404-notfound-error-or-400-bad-request-error-the-requests-worked-in-postman) , but it still gives the same error.
The HTTP Request configuration is:

```
<http:request-config name="HTTPS_Request_configuration" doc:name="HTTP Request configuration" doc:id="abd3aa76-ab4e-4804-83e6-6b1ae984007a" >
    <http:request-connection host="testhost" maxConnections="-1" connectionIdleTimeout="6000" responseBufferSize="1024" protocol="HTTPS">
        <reconnection >
            <reconnect frequency="5000" count="5" />
        </reconnection>
        <http:authentication >
            <oauth:client-credentials-grant-type clientId="${secure::api.clientid}" clientSecret="${secure::api.clientsecret}" tokenUrl="https://testhost/tokens.path" scopes="document.read Documents.write" refreshTokenWhen="#[attributes.statusCode == 401]">
            </oauth:client-credentials-grant-type>
        </http:authentication>
    </http:request-connection>
</http:request-config>
```

The same values work fine in Postman.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1W3x.png)

Token response in Postman:

```
{
"access_token": "~3000 character long string",
 "scope": "whatever is mentioned in the config",
 "expires_in": 300,
 "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

Please advise if anything is wrong with the configuration or what I can change to get a success response?

Comment: Do you have any luck with this? I am having the exact same issue. Works in Postman with every header being the same in a code enviroment but only getting back a 403

Answer (score 0):

The URL for the token seems different from the screenshot, but since it is masked it could be not the real one. Scopes should be comma separated. In your HTTP configuration are space separated and completely masked in the Postman screenshot. Screenshots are bad in general for troubleshooting and you [should not use them in Stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557) unless it is a UI error.

Since you can not probably share some confidential details you should do the troubleshooting yourself by comparing both HTTP requests (from Mule and from Postman) to understand what could be the differences and adjust the configuration to match. Instead of a screenshot, use Postman 'Code' button and copy the request as HTTP.

Then in the Mule 4 application change the logging configuration to enable [HTTP wire logging](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-Enable-HTTP-Wire-Logging). This will print to the log the HTTP request.

Take both HTTP requests side by side and look for differences in how they may differ.

Comment: I got the HTTP logs through wire logging & postman code, there are slight differences in both requests. For starters, Cloudhub appends port no 443 for HTTPS request, there are additional headers like x-anypnt-app-worker, x-correlation-id, User-Agent, Connection & Accept. There is also a difference in 'Authorization' header, mule request is in small case. Not sure any of this is causing problem. Postman request has scopes separated by space & it still works. The error message in Mule logs is the same: User is not authorized to access this resource with an explicit deny"

Comment: CloudHub may append headers to requests received by your application but it doesn't change anything in HTTP requests *from* your application. The Mule HTTP Connector may add HTTP headers but usually they are not a cause of issues. If the case of an HTTP header (ie Authorization vs authorization) is causing an issue the remote server is at fault since HTTP headers should be case-insensitive. Postman may define things differently, but the Mule HTTP connector may not be able to parse the scopes. Are the requests different in scopes? Add as much as you can share to the question.

Comment: The scopes are same in both requests. The silver lining is there is a bearer token in both requests, which means the user is authenticated but when scopes are comma separated in Mule request, it says 400 Bad request: Error from cloudfront, invalid_scope, so I guess the remote server expects scope as space separated.

Comment: Do you mean that the HTTP request from the HTTP Request connector is receiving the token? Is the request working then?